# Navigation Bar is too small

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am working on an iPad app and when I try to put the navigation bar on the first view controller, it fits in the main storyboard but is too small (also comes in contact with the status bar) when I run the simulator (as seen in the picture below):

[image]

The width and height in the storyboard are set to regular, not sure if it is relevant to this question. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're just adding a navigation bar. Are you sure you don't want a navigation controller?

If you do just want the navigation bar the you need to add constraints to pin it to the left and right of the screen.

Click the "add constraints" button and pin to left right and top.

Answer (score 2):

Click on your view and go to Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller.